# Coupled differential equations in Matlab's ode45

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I am trying to numerically solve the following coupled differential equations in Matlab:

$$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{df}{dz}=i\delta f(z)+i\kappa b(z)\\
\ \\
\frac{db}{dz}=-i\delta b(z)-i\kappa f(z)
\end{array}$$

I have defined these differential equations in a function file:

```
function [dNdz]= eqs(x,N)
% Parameters:
kappa_D = 0.7;
v = 0.04;
delta = (2*kappa_D/v).*((1./x)-1);
kappa = x.*kappa_D;
% Equations:
dNdz=zeros(2,1);
dNdz(1) = 1i.*delta(x).*N(1)+1i.*kappa(x).*N(2);
dNdz(2) = -1i.*delta(x).*N(2)-1i.*kappa(x).*N(1);
end
```

Then I tried to solve them using Matlab's ode45 function:

```
[x,N] =ode45(@(x,N) eqs(x,N),x,[1 0]);

R = abs((N(:,2)./N(:,1))).^2;

plot(x,R)
```

What I am trying to plot is the absolute-value-squared of the ratio of the two solutions $R$ given above. My results look like this:

[image]

But this is not the right solution. I know that from the analytic solutions to these differential equations, R must be:

$$\boxed{R=\frac{\sinh^{2}(\alpha L)}{\cosh^{2}(\alpha L)-\frac{\delta^{2}}{\kappa^{2}}}}$$

This equation produces the plot:

```
% Parameters
npt = 2^10; x = linspace(0.95,1.05,npt); x = 1./x;
kappa_D = 0.7; v = 0.04;
delta = (2*kappa_D/v).*((1./x)-1);
kappa = x.*kappa_D; a = sqrt(kappa.^2-delta.^2);
L=10;
% Plot
R = ((sinh(a*L)).^2)./(((cosh(a*L)).^2)-((delta.^2)./(kappa.^2)));
plot(x,R);
```

[image]

This is very strange. The numerical solution has to be in agreement with the analytic one. What is the problem here? Is there something wrong with my Matlab syntax or the way I am using ode45?

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are these functions `delta(x)` and `kappa(x)`? Do these function calls give the same values as the above defined variables `delta` and `kappa`?

Comment: Yes. They are exactly the same equations and give the same values. I just saved them under separate function files.

Comment: Why do you duplicate your work, that only leads to hard-to-trace errors? Just use the variables that you directly computed above (that is, remove the `(x)`), no external functions are necessary.

Comment: Yes, I have removed the (x). But I am still not getting the right solutions to the DEs. I am wondering if there is something wrong with the way I am using the function?